# JSON API returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, dom

When I try to show the height and weight from an API (http://thedogapi.com/), I get an error:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'metric')**

If I comment the "items.height.metric" everything works great, but I have to show these results also.

From a page before I get the ID, as I click on an item from a list, that brings me to the second page, showing something like "http://localhost:3000/config/?id=2" (So, I clicked on the second item).
GitHub: https://github.com/fvrabelo/tiroNewDogApi
Any help? love y'all

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4D90.png)

```js
import {React} from 'react'
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


const Page = () =>{
    // identifica ID na url
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const id = urlParams.get('id');

// fetch da raca baseado no ID passado pela url
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
      const getBreeds = async () =>{
        const res = await fetch(
         `https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/${id}`
        );
        const data = await res.json();
        setItems(data)
        
      }
      getBreeds()
    }, [])


//fetch da imagem
function getImage(imageId) {
    fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/${imageId}`)
    .then(r =>r.json())
    .then(response=> {
      const data = response

      document.querySelector(".image").src = data.url;
    })
  }


    return(
        <div className="" 
             style={{"display": "flex",
             "position":"relative",
             "justify-content": "center",
             "align-items": "center",
             'flex-direction': "column",
             "maxWidth":"100%",
             "maxHeight":"100%"}}>

            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-center"  style={{"marginTop":"5px"}}>Breed name</h6>
            <h5 className="card-title text-center">{items.name}</h5>
            
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-center" style={{"marginTop":"5px"}}>Bred for</h6>
            <h5 className="card-title text-center">{items.bred_for}</h5>
            
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-center" style={{"marginTop":"5px"}}>Group</h6>
            <h5 className="card-title text-center">{items.breed_group}</h5>
            
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-center" style={{"marginTop":"5px"}}>Temperament</h6>
            <h5 className="card-title text-center">{items.temperament}</h5>
            
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-center" style={{"marginTop":"5px"}}>Life span</h6>
            <h5 className="card-title text-center">{items.life_span}</h5>
            
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-center" style={{"marginTop":"5px"}}>Height</h6>
            <h5 className="card-title text-center">{items.height.metric}</h5>

            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-center" style={{"marginTop":"5px"}}>Weight</h6>
            <h5 className="card-title text-center">{items.weight.metric}</h5>


            <img className ="image" 
            src={getImage(items.reference_image_id) }
            style={{ "maxHeight": "300px", "maxWidth": "300px", "marginBottom":"15px" }}/>


            
            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-primary">Home</Link>
            

        </div>
        
    );
}

export default Page;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

For now I have something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNxm2.png)

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the fields `height.metric` do not exist for some dogs (and for others they do).
So you have to handle that possibility:

```
{ items.height.metric &&
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-center" style={{"marginTop":"5px"}}>Height</h6>
            <h5 className="card-title text-center">{items.height.metric}</h5>
}
{ items.weight.metric &&
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-center" style={{"marginTop":"5px"}}>Weight</h6>
            <h5 className="card-title text-center">{items.weight.metric}</h5>
}
```

Comment: I thought the same, but for example the "first dog":
https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/1

It has height and weight, but returns the error :'/